# Docker image defaults to python 3.6 even though I install python 3.7

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to set up a Docker image based on Ubuntu 18.04 that runs some code with Python 3.7

The dockerfile specifically mentions installing python 3.7 but in the image binary folder there is also python 3.6 that the image uses as default and which I don't even need.

What change would I need to make in order to only have python 3.7 on the image?

The dockerfile currently looks like this:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

#format changes required for asammdf v3.4.0
ENV LANG C.UTF-8
ENV LC_ALL C.UTF-8

#install python 3.7 and pip
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    python3.7 \
    python3-pip

#set main entry point as working directory
WORKDIR /

RUN pip3 install --upgrade setuptools

RUN alias python3=/usr/bin/python3.7
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

Later details:

Added the `alias` command hoping that it would work but it seems to be ignored in the dockerfile, the execution still goes to python3.6

The requirements installation works fine but installs all packages in the 3.6 directory so even if I manually use the python3.7 execution while in the container, it doesn't see the installed modules

Comment: why not to use `python:3.7` as your base image ?

Comment: Avoid using ubuntu18.04, it is possible that it already has some default python version installed.

Comment: This is not really an option, it needs to be ubuntu18.04

Comment: Your `alias` command in the Dockerfile will only apply to the one `RUN` line it is in.  Each `RUN` line is a new process, and `alias` only works for the current process.  You would need a more permanent way of replacing the default Ubuntu Python 3 installation, possibly with symbolic links or the `alternatives` suite.  This approach has the possibility of breaking included software that depends on the Ubuntu supplied Python 3.6.  You would be better off (and have smaller images) using a Docker image built for Python 3.7

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu 18.04 comes preinstalled with Python 3.6. How are you invoking the python binary execution to run your code?
Try explicitly stating the complete python 3.7 binary path to execute your code.

```
/usr/lib/python3.7 myCode.py
```

That should work for ubuntu 18.04
I checked the location of the python 3.7 binary using

```
whereis python3.7
```

Using the official python image would be efficient though.

Comment: I added a command in the dockerfile `RUN alias python3=/usr/bin/python3.7` but it still defaults to 3.6 for some reason

Comment: You should use `CMD alias python3=/usr/bin/python3.7` instead of `RUN`. `CMD` would execute that command upon container creation.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using [offical python image](https://hub.docker.com/_/python) which contains everything which you need.

```
docker run -it --rm --name my_python3.7 python:3.7-alpine3.9
```

You can find the offical Dockerfile [here](https://github.com/docker-library/python/blob/c3233a936f58bee7c6899d3e381f23ed12cfc7a8/3.7/alpine3.10/Dockerfile).

The **bonus** with the above image is  you will get python3.7 in just **under 100 BM**

**update:**

So you can use this image as the base image in your Dockerfile

```
python:3.7-alpine3.9

ENV LANG C.UTF-8
ENV LC_ALL C.UTF-8
.
.
.
```

Comment: So no change to the dockerfile then?

Comment: @Andrei change `ubuntu:18.04` to `alpine:3.7-alpine3.9`

Comment: @Andrei yes you can use this as a base image. update answer

Comment: This seems to create more problems than it solves. I have those "apt" commands which I replaced with the "apk" equivalent but it doesn't work with the rest of the requirements. Thanks for the effort though

Comment: where it's not working, you can update the question or ask another question so we can help. if you want to work with docker for a long time and then I will suggest going with alpine.

Comment: Well the linux commands for navigating the directories such as `ls` and `cd` don't work if I use this method and I need them

Comment: no its wrong, all linux command should work, there `sh` not `bash` in alpine. alpine is linux base image. **A minimal Docker image based on Alpine Linux with a complete package index and only 5 MB in size!** https://hub.docker.com/_/alpine